# How to make PV_Log and PV_Summaries tables that will store pv info with mysql?

Tags: mysql

Im new to mysql and I would want some help .
Actually, I made  a pv log table and want to make a additional table named pv_summaries that will be the table that holds up to 100 of the aggregate value of the PV number for each day of pv_logs details of each page. I would want some mysql sample.Sorry for my poor English.

```
create table pv_logs(
id int (11)auto_increment primary key,
dt date,controller varchar(64),action varchar(64),
params varchar(64),url varchar(255),ua varchar(255),
ua_type varchar(255),ip varchar(255),is_crawler tinyint(4),
created datetime,modified datetime
);
```

Comment: what are the data that should be contained in pv_summary table?

Comment: I want to create a table to store the result of counting the overall ranking of the daily. 
The purpose will be the table that holds up to 100 of the aggregate value of the PV number for each 
day of pv_logs, details of each page. However, I still have not idea what kind of data I must use . It would be greate if I can have a sample table.